# can gourmet (n.) refer to food?

Tags: meaning

According to Merriam Webster, Gourmet as a noun refers to a person, and as an adjective describes food. Can it refer to food when it's a noun? I remember seeing such usage but can't be certain by looking it up in the dictionary.

Can I scream

> Gourmet!

when seeing delicious food? Is it used as a noun or adjective?

Comment: You can *exclaim* or *cry out* or drool as you utter *gourmet*. Screaming children, scream in sheer fright, a screaming match etc, *scream* is rarely used positively

Comment: *I don't need you to tell me how good my coffee is, okay? I'm the one who buys it. I know how good it is. When Bonnie goes shopping she buys ....*

Comment: @Mari-LouA: "Screaming with excitement" is pretty common - it's positive in the sense that the person doing the screaming is happy, though I guess there's an implication their reaction may be out of control / over the top!

Comment: ''You scream, I scream, we all scream for ice cream!''

Answer (score 8):

Please don't scream anything when seeing food.

"Gourmet" can be used attributively of food.  "This is a gourmet steak".  It is not often used in the predicate ?"This steak is gourmet."

It wouldn't make sense to say "Gourmet!"  As a noun "A gourmet" is always a person, and never food.

Comment: Why can't I scream "Gourmet!" for the same reason as "Delicious!"?

Comment: @Tim - people who scream anything much of the time are intensely annoying and may be thought to be crazy.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Tim probably just meant using this word in some exclamation,  not necessarily screaming.

Comment: I think the whole *don't scream* thing was just a joke lol

Comment: When an adjective is used as an interjection, it's implicitly predicative: the implication of "delicious!" is "[this food is] delicious!". As already noted in the answer, this usage is marginal for "gourmet". These kinds of uses are also culturally mediated, and may not be strictly determined by rules of grammar. (But I suppose it could be argued that nouns like "gourmet" that can be used attributively just don't really become proper adjectives when used that way, but instead form part of a noun phrase. Keep in mind that natural language grammar is fundamentally descriptive, not prescriptive.)

Comment: Many people would be uncomfortable if you called them delicious, except in certain very specific contexts....

Comment: @Zimano - I was very struck in recent years by the way in which American far-right-wing people often accuse 'liberals' of 'screaming' when the liberals are disagreeing with them or objecting to something they said. True screaming is a very unpleasant sound.

Comment: In English, single adjectives don't form complete sentences. It is a little odd, therefore, to say "Delicious!". You might say "That's delicious" or "It looks delicious", or informally an exclamatory sound like "Yum!".  It would be even more odd to use a formal adjective, and one is normally only attributive. So you'd not say "Gourmet!"  In any case you should *say* and not *scream*. @tim

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Screaming people may be considered crazy -- or American! (My favorite American is in the bedroom next door, so I learned to deal with it ;-). )

Comment: The other kind of people who 'scream' about things are those who are very camp, it just occurs to me. What my father called 'theatrical types'.